# Getting APP_ID for Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, app-id

I'm following the [Facebook tutorial for Android Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sso).

Right here:

[image]

Number 1 clearly says to change Number 2 to my "APP_ID" but I don't know where to find what my APP_ID is. How can I find this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to: http://developers.facebook.com/apps and click on your app there. You will see your App Id and App Secret.